# lesscss print style

Tags: javascript, css, less

I want using lesscss for print,
but it seems, the browser don't recongize the @media `print`,

since I don't want embbed

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="themes/css/print.css" media="print">
```

into page.

can anyone help on this issue? lesscss sourse code address is here

[https://github.com](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L988)

thanks

Comment: Your link should point to a `.less` file for it to work, not a `.css` file.

Comment: no, I mean I don't want to using .css/.less file. My my less is working fine, but inside the style.less, the @media print not working

Comment: Please share you code as well

Comment: my code is simple, you can just download h5bp template + lesscss, convert style.css to style.less, run on an Apache server or IIS(register .less for MINEYTPE)...and trying to put print style at @media print

Comment: @mike - we don't want to have to go through that effort of downloading your less and running apache just to help you with your problem. Please provide your code right here, so we can see it easily and then we can help you. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="http://worldMaps.org/maps/styles/growth.less" media="all">
```

The important part is the **media="all"**, otherwise it will not correctly parse your @media print {.no-print {display:none;}} inside your linked less file.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to embed less-styles for media print: the media attribute within the link tag worked for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="print.less" media="print">
```

The `media="print"` is essential as less by default inserts compiled styles as `media="screen"`.

Answer (score 1):

While I was using .less, the web developer tool option for displaying print styles wasn't rendering for me.

**My solution**, although may not render 100% correctly depending on the browser, is to switch the **@media print** and **@media screen** properties in the style sheet so that on page load, the print styles are rendered.

**I don't suggest this solution if:**

- You need to trace both screen and print styles
- You need precise measurements

**I do suggest this solution if:**

- You don't want to continually go back to print preview after every
  adjustment
- You are willing to sacrifice the above in order to test content arrangement and styling structure

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lesscss, use @media property into "less" file.

Like this:

```
@media: mobile;

.mixin (@a) when (@media = mobile) { ... }
.mixin (@a) when (@media = desktop) { ... }
```

And import file normaly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="themes/css/print.less">
```

http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions